# Output each word in string to a new line

Tags: c++, string

I'm designing a function which has 1 input parameter : string. The function takes the contents of this string, and outputs each word to a new line. Currently, this function does everything except output the last word in the string. Here's the functions code:

```
void outputPhrase(string newPhrase)
{
    string ok;
    for (int i = 0; i < newPhrase.length(); i++)
    {
        ok += newPhrase[i];
        if (isspace(newPhrase.at(i)))
        {
            cout << ok << endl;
            ok.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < newPhrase.length(); i++)
    {
        ok += newPhrase[i];

        if (isspace(newPhrase.at(i)) || i==newPhrase.length()-1)
        {
            cout << ok << endl;

            ok.clear();

        }


    }
```

Comment: My version checks if isspace or if for has reached the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function to do your task,

```
void split(string newPhrase)
{
    istringstream iss(newPhrase);

    do
    {
        string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        cout << sub << endl;
    } while (iss);
}
```

Remember to include < string > and < sstream > in your code.